# Is Qt only for cpp coding

Tags: ide

I am a newbie to the coding world and a friend recommend Qt creater for me since I told him I wanted to code in cpp but I want to know if it is possible to use Qt to code in java or anything else and how do you go about it if it is possible

Answer (score 1):

[PySide](https://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/) allows you to use Qt in Python and is very well respected. For Java, [Qt Jambi](http://qtjambi.org/) appears well maintained, and allows you to use Qt in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Qt was originally for only for C++, but people have built bindings in for it to be used in other languages as poster @xxdkxx pointed out. However, I would only recommend doing this if you are familiar with Qt and prefer it, but have project constraints that limit you to a specific language.

If you are looking to just get started making GUI's and you are more familiar with Java, I would suggest using [Swing](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-functionality.html), or if you are using Eclipse use Eclipse's built-in GUI tool called [WindowBuilder](https://eclipse.org/windowbuilder/). It leverages Swing and SWT Designer (another popular Java GUI builder) to make GUI-building easy for developers with a wide range of experience, from multiple days to multiple years. Some say that it won't give you quite as much flexibility as just using the low level Swing or AWT (Abstract Window Toolset) components, and people often complain that this autogenerates too much code unnecessarily, but often it is enough, and its easier to start out with.